# Remove precision from price of a product

Tags: product, magento-1.9, price

As I said in the title, I want to remove precision from price ( ***.00*** )

I did these :

1. In **app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php**

in

```
public function format()
```

I changed

```
 return $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
```

to

```
 return $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
```

2. In **/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Price.php**

in

```
public function getEscapedValue()
```

I changed

```
 return number_format($value, 2, null, '');
```

to

```
 return number_format($value, 0, null, '');
```

3. In **js/varien/js.js**

I changed

```
var precision = isNaN(format.precision = Math.abs(format.precision)) ? 2 : format.precision;
var requiredPrecision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision;
```

to

```
var precision = 0;
var requiredPrecision = 0;
```

4. And in **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php**

I changed

```
public function roundPrice($price)
    {
        return round($price, 2);
    }
```

to

```
 public function roundPrice($price)
    {
        return round($price, 0);
    }
```

Then I cleared the cache, and reindexed Magento (which is i version1.9), But the precision didn't remove, Am I missing something? what should I do?

Comment: Always override core classes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could take a look at http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html I have never used it but I can see you can manage the decimal places and more

"Who needs cents anyway?
You can display price without zero cents. Example: display 49 instead of 49.00, but leave 49.99 unchanged."

Plus it free :-)

Comment: will it change the invoice value?

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but does not really have a programmatic correct answer.

$_product is your product object model.

```
$price = ($_product->getFinalPrice() != 0) ? $_product->getFinalPrice()
            : $_product->getPrice();
        if ($round) {
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore(null);
            $currency = $store->getCurrentCurrency();
            return $currency->formatPrecision($price, 0, array(), true, false);
        }
        return Mage::helper('core')->currencyByStore($price)
```