# Rounding Product Price triggers tax issue

Tags: magento-1.9, rounding, tax-rounding

**It's not the duplicate of [this qst](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36600/remove-precision-from-price-of-a-product).**

I am not trying to hide decimal, but trying to round the product price. But in same time not rounding the tax. So tax should be calculated having `2 decimal`, but product price should be rounded to none-decimal.

**Org Qst**

I am trying to round product prices by changing following function in `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency` and it works:

```
/**
     * Format price to currency format
     *
     * @param float $price
     * @param array $options
     * @param bool $includeContainer
     * @param bool $addBrackets
     * @return string
     */
    public function format($price, $options = array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
    {
        //return $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
        return $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
    }
```

**However, above changes triggers tax issue.** Because it also rounds my tax.

For example: when my product price is $1629 and qty in cart is 1, then my cart total area will look like this:

```
Subtotal                 $1,629
Grand Total Excl. GST    $1,481
GST (10%)                  $148
Grand Total Incl. GST    $1,629
```

Here, actual tax is $148.10 but because of rounding it is shown as $148. This is against the tax rule set by gov.

**My question**

How can I round all product prices but show GST with at least 2 decimal point?

OR

**What I would like to have?**

```
GST (10%)               $148.10
Grand Total Incl. GST    $1,629
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove precision from price of a product](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36600/remove-precision-from-price-of-a-product)

Comment: :( It's not the duplicate.